# changed output directory and now my project can't compile or empty files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I have net6.0 project in mvs 2022 and when i changed output dir from F disk to $(SolutionDir) which in C disk my files removes from project, but they still exist in folder

[image: before changing]

[image: after changing]

I created new one with $(SolutionDir) at the start, but then i changed it to $(SolutionDir)bin and now i got errors (i have Base project that contains Config and etc which used in Login project and second one)

Error   NETSDK1022  Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Compile' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems. The duplicate items were: 'Config.cs'; 'Log.cs'; 'network\Connection.cs'; 'network\packets\ReceivePacket.cs'; 'network\packets\SendPacket.cs'; 'Utils.cs'   Base

If i set it to prev output dir it would be normal. I never loved 2022 but 2019 doesnt have Net6.0+. So what i should to do to prevent creating new project every fcking time i want to change output dir ?

Comment: Hi, have you tried adding Remove before Include in csproj? Remove first and then include, this can solve the problem. It is more useful and convenient when you need to modify the compilation attributes of a small number of classes in a large number of classes.